# Неверный результат поиска в Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Есть коллекция в монго, делаю запрос 
db.favorite.find({user_id: "44"}, {name: 1})
Числа хранятся в БД строкой, давно так делаю, что-то плохо искало по числам, всё работало, но счас почему-то выдаётся только 1 строка, а в базе их существенно больше с таким значением. Предполагаю что какая-то проблема с индексом монги, но хотелось бы знать подробней от чего такое бывает и как можно избежать в дальнейшем. Счас буду пробовать переформировать индекс

Answer (score 1):

Может, у вас есть документы, где числа хранятся как числа, в таком случае вы их не найдете.

Ищите по числу - находите только числа

Ищите по строке - находите только строки.

Comment: В том-то и дело что там именно строки, и ищу я их как строки. Причём пробовал искать как числа - не находит. сделал reindex по коллекции - стала работать как надо